# I can't Insert this data in my column in SQL

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE ACUPAN (
    EMP_NO INT ,
    SURNAME VARCHAR (20),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR (20),
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR (20),
    RATEPERDAY INT,
    NOMOFWORK INT,
    SALARY INT,
    
);
SELECT*FROM ACUPAN;

INSERT INTO ACUPAN VALUES (30012,'AVILES', 'KATE', 'HRD' , 740, ,12);
```

Why i cant insert this DATA in my column?

[image]

Comment: switch `, 740, ,12);` with `740, NULL, 12);` instead. You can't just put nothing between two commas.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
INSERT INTO ACUPAN VALUES (30012,'AVILES', 'KATE', 'HRD' , 740, 0, 12);
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO ACUPAN VALUES (30012,'AVILES', 'KATE', 'HRD' , 740, NULL, 12);
```

You can't have an empty value between comma's.
You can define its empty by putting `NULL` or `0` in case of an `integer` or `""` in case of a `string`

Answer (score 0):

In your insert statement you have a **2** commas near the end of the statement `740, ,12);`. Basically, the `MySQL` expects to have a value between those empty commas.

change this

```
INSERT INTO ACUPAN VALUES (30012,'AVILES', 'KATE', 'HRD' , 740, ,12);
```

into this

```
INSERT INTO ACUPAN VALUES (30012, 'AVILES', 'KATE', 'HRD', 740, 0, 12); 
                                                           -- ^ only one comma here
```

> I put `0` as the value of `NOMOFWORK` column because its type is `INT` and it doesn't have a default value. You should put the right value instead of `0`.